# Understanding "this" in functions

Tags: javascript, this

I have this code:

```
let bar = () => {
  let x = 5; 
  console.log(this.x)
}

bar();
```

It does not work. I also have this code:

```
let bar = () => {
  this.x = 5; 
  console.log(this.x)
}

bar();
```

It does work. I want to make sure I understand why. As I understand it, simply declaring a variable within a function does not make it a value on the function object. Only when declaring this.___ = ____ does it actually become a value on the object.

...is that right?

Comment: `this` isn’t the function object, but it’s true that declaring variables doesn’t put them on `this`.

Comment: Try running that in Chrome and pause break the code so you can analyze what exactly `this` is. It's the same `this` as is visible when you're calling `bar();`  (use the dev console)

Comment: `this` in this case is the Window object.

Comment: go through some research if not found provide results of your effort then you will get answer from here

Comment: Thank you. It's nice when people answer the question with information.

Comment: You should read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of functions in JavaScript with respect to `this`: arrow functions and non-arrow functions.

#### function () {}

For non-arrow functions, you can think of `this` as just another parameter. Where a typical parameter would be set by passing an argument:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x;
}

foo(1);  // returns 1
```

the `this` parameter is set by *how* the function is called:

```
function foo() {
    return this;
}

var obj = { foo: foo };


foo();         // returns undefined, because it’s not one of the following
               // special forms

obj.foo();     // returns obj, because the function was called with dot notation

obj['foo']();  // returns obj, because bracket notation and dot notation
               // work the same

foo.call(1);   // returns 1, because a function’s `call` method
               // sets `this` explicitly
```

```
new foo();     // returns a new object of type `foo`‽ read up!
```

Every non-arrow function has this implicit parameter called `this`. The top scope, outside any function, also has a `this`. It can be a few different things, depending on your environment; you can safely ignore it.

#### () => {}

Arrow functions don’t have the implicit `this` parameter. They use the `this` from their containing scope, like any other variable. In other words, in complete opposition to non-arrow functions, how they’re called doesn’t matter at all; it’s about where the `() => { … }` is located.

```
// `this` outside `foo`…

const foo = () => {
    // is the same as `this` inside `foo`. always.
    return this;
};
```

Now, tying it all together, your arrow functions are in the top scope, outside of any other function. That means they have whatever `this` was in the top scope. If that isn’t `undefined`, you *can* set values on it, like you’re doing with `this.x = 5;` in an arrow function. It’s the same `this` every time, though, and it’s certainly not referring to “the function object”.

As for the first example: declaring variables, like with `let x = 5;`, has nothing to do with `this` at all.

Comment: Nice and concise. I wish this would be part of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196 though.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, I don’t really know where to put the abridged versions of these things compared to the detailed spec answers. Another answer to that question…?